# How to I create an If then do statement that only runs a macro for a certain department?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a code that outputs a report for multiple departments at my work, I want one piece to run only if the department is set to marketing. With my current %if %then %do statement, it is running regardless of what the department is set to. Everything runs and prints fine, I would like it to not run if I set the department to anything other than marketing! Thanks, Here is my code

```
%macro redcap (demo);
%if &dept. ="Marketing" %then %do;
proc sql;
    create table redcap&demo. as
    select
    &demo.,
        count(distinct email) as Num_Users
    from startredcap2
        group by &demo.
        order by num_users desc;
quit;
%end;
%else %do;

%end;
proc print data = redcap&demo.;
run;


%mend; 
%redcap (demo = funds);
%redcap (demo = programs);
```

Comment: Please show examples of values you have assigned to the undefined macro variable DEPT.  Do they include the quotes you are using in your %IF statement?

Comment: The original macro is %let dept = Marketing, it can be set to Finance, or other departments, but I only want it to run if set to marketing. When removing the quotations in the % if statement, it still runs regardless

Comment: Quotes are just text to the macro processor so either include quotes around `&dept` or drop them from around `Marketing`.

Comment: @Mkrogen, right now this does what you expect - it won't run unless `&dept` equals `"MARKETING"`.  You need to show a complete program that will do the behavior you show in a new SAS session (and with any data we need provided to us, as dummy data in datalines), or we can't really help you.

Comment: This code is the one that is not working as expected, regardless of what dept is set to it runs. What else should I be giving you to help?

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to upcase your macro variables in cases like this for if/then/else.  You can optionally strip blanks with `%cmpres()` if the macro variable might contain leading or trailing spaces. For example:

```
%let dept = marketing;

%if(%upcase(%cmpres(&dept.) ) ) = MARKETING %then %do;
    %put This is the &dept. department.;
%end;
```